# Rails app not saving nested form model data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested-forms

When I am saving the applicant model it is not saving the nested model data to data base. I have pasted my controller code, model code & passing parameters

My parameters are :

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5F8h7qG2pez9Rsutnq3JXYyXbPkbVJAlgfIfsE1bdUw=", "applicant"=>
{"job_id"=>"1", "first_name"=>"sanyam", "location"=>"", "email"=>"", "mob_no"=>"", "alternative_no"=>"", "last_name"=>"jain", "works_attributes"=>{"1366604495995"=>
{"title"=>"M Tech", "company_name"=>"", "start_month"=>"", "start_year"=>"", "end_month"=>"", "end_year"=>"", "description"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1366604506595"=>
{"title"=>"B Tech", "company_name"=>"", "start_month"=>"", "start_year"=>"", "end_month"=>"", "end_year"=>"", "description"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "linkedin"=>"", 
"twitter"=>"", "facebook"=>"", "message"=>""}, "submit"=>""}
```

My controller code is:

```
def createProfile
@applicant = Applicant.new(params[:applicant])
@applicant.save
end
```

My applicant model is

```
class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :location, :email, :mob_no, :alternative_no, :linkedin, :facebook, :twitter, :message, :resume, :job_id
has_many :works, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :educations, :dependent => :destroy
attr_accessible :works_attributes, :educations_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :works, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

accepts_nested_attributes_for :educations, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

My work model is

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :applicant_id, :company_name, :description, :end_month, :end_year, :start_month, :start_year, :title
belongs_to :applicant
validates_associated :applicant
end
```

Comment: in your controller user "save!" instead of "save" and post the raised error

Comment: also you need to add to attr_accessable in applicant model  :works_attributes ,:educations_Attributes

Comment: tried both of this, its not working

Comment: i already have made :works_attributes ,:educations_Attributes accessible

Comment: make sure the content field in both are not nil because 
you reject saving work and education if the content field in both

Comment: ok, can you please explain it in detail, i am not getting it

Comment: coming params of request do not have :content key and 
reject_if in the accepted_nested_attributes_for says that if the content of works is nil or empty string do not save it and the same thing in education 
remove reject_if part as ** validates_associated :applicant ** validate the associated object so need for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reject_if that you have specified says that it should not save the child model when the params does not have :content in it. So make sure that your params has content attribute with a value in it. Ur params should look sort of like this:

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5F8h7qG2pez9Rsutnq3JXYyXbPkbVJAlgfIfsE1bdUw=", "applicant"=>
{"job_id"=>"1", "first_name"=>"sanyam", "location"=>"", "email"=>"", "mob_no"=>"", "alternative_no"=>"", "last_name"=>"jain", "works_attributes"=>{"1366604495995"=>
{"title"=>"M Tech", "company_name"=>"", "start_month"=>"", "start_year"=>"", "end_month"=>"", "end_year"=>"", "description"=>"", "content"=>"some content", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1366604506595"=>
{"title"=>"B Tech", "company_name"=>"", "start_month"=>"", "start_year"=>"", "end_month"=>"", "end_year"=>"", "description"=>"", "content"=>"some content", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "linkedin"=>"", 
"twitter"=>"", "facebook"=>"", "message"=>""}, "submit"=>""}

Comment: its helps me a lot. Really thanks for it.
but i want to know that why should it necessary to have one field named content in it?

Comment: reject_if means that, you should reject the save if the condition that you give evaluates to false. Since your condition checks  { |a| a[:content].blank? }, you would need :content params.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to two attr_accessible if child table data is not gettting saved

attr_accessible :first_name
attr_accessible :works_attributes, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :works